# Flutter/IOS Low Power Mode

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to figure out if the user has enabled low power mode on their device (IOS).

The Apple documentation says it goes like this:

```
@property(readonly, getter=isLowPowerModeEnabled) BOOL lowPowerModeEnabled;
```

Is there a possibility to do this with flutter (perhaps a package that's also compatible with android)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MethodChannel` to communicate with the platform and retrieve informations you need. Also you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/power) (`power`) plugin for Flutter (It's under development but currently you can get device low power mode using it). Here is the sample code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _lowPowerMode = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPowerState();
  }

  Future<void> initPowerState() async {
    bool lowPowerMode;

    try {
      lowPowerMode = await Power.isLowPowerMode;
    } on PlatformException {
      lowPowerMode = false;
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _lowPowerMode = lowPowerMode;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Power example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Low power mode is ${_lowPowerMode ? 'on' : 'off'}'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```